# Isoceles Triangles on a Grid Proof

Tags: geometry

Given: A Finite Set of Unit Squares on a Large Grid. 
If we were to choose one of those sets of unit squares, we see that the squares of the set are tiled with isoceles right triangles, each with a hypotenuse of 2. Also these triangles do not overlap with each other and they do not extend past the set and all of the set is fully covered by the triangles. Aslo, the hypotenuse of every triangle lies along a grid line and all the vertices of the triangles lie at the corners of the squares.

Prove: All the number of triangles must be a multiple of four.

I have somewhat of an answer to this but I am not completely sure if it is correct. Is someone willing to look at my solution and give some feedback on it.

Comment: This question comes from the current USAMTS Round 3 problem set ([problem 5](http://www.usamts.org/Tests/Problems_26_3.pdf)). This question will remain locked until after the submission deadline of 19 Jan 2015.

Comment: This question was asked again: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111897/a-finite-square-of-unit-squares-is-chosen-triangle-proof-problem

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the set of squares (as in the USAMTS problem statement)
and let $T$ be the set of triangles.

Due to the constraints on the placement of the triangles,
each triangle overlaps two squares, and each of these overlapping regions is a
right triangle whose hypotenuse is a diagonal of the overlapped square.
We can map the squares and triangles to the nodes and edges of a graph;
let each square with an overlapping triangle correspond to a node, and let each
triangle correspond to an edge connecting the two squares it overlaps.

Given a square in $S$ and a triangle in $T$ that overlaps the given square, 
the "other" half of the square is covered by a different triangle.
That is, exactly two triangles must overlap each square.
Hence in the corresponding graph,
each node has exactly two edges connected to it.
From this and from the fact that there are only a finite number of squares in $S$,
we can deduce that the graph consists of a finite number of disjoint cycles.

Give each edge of the graph an orientation so that you can trace each cycle
always traveling in the same direction as each edge you traverse.
This gives us eight kinds of triangles in $T$,
based on the two squares overlapped by the triangle, 
the direction from the square the triangle "comes from" to the square the triangle
"goes to" (orienting "from" and "to" the same as for the corresponding graph edge),
and whether the edge of the triangle in the "from" square is a left diagonal
(from the upper left corner to the lower right) or a right diagonal:

1. A triangle from the right diagonal of one square to the left diagonal
   of the square to the right.

   A triangle from the right diagonal of one square to the left diagonal
   of the square above.

   A triangle from the left diagonal of one square to the right diagonal
   of the square above.

   A triangle from the left diagonal of one square to the right diagonal
   of the square to the left.

   A triangle from the right diagonal of one square to the left diagonal
   of the square to the left.

   A triangle from the right diagonal of one square to the left diagonal
   of the square below.

   A triangle from the left diagonal of one square to the right diagonal
   of the square below.

   A triangle from the left diagonal of one square to the right diagonal
   of the square to the right.

Let the number of triangles of each type be respectively $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_8.$

Now consider a square whose overlapping triangles meet on the square's left diagonal.
If the edge into the corresponding node came from the square to the right or below,
the edge out of that node must go to the square to the left or above;
that is, for each type 1 or 2 triangle there must be a type 3 or 8 triangle, so
$$n_1 + n_2 = n_3 + n_8.$$
Similarly,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
n_3 + n_4 &=& n_2 + n_5, \\
n_5 + n_6 &=& n_4 + n_7, \ \mbox{and}\\
n_7 + n_8 &=& n_6 + n_1.
\end{eqnarray}$$

If we cut each square along *both* diagonals,
we dissect it into four small right triangles, one above the center of the square,
one below, one to the left, and one to the right.
There must be an equal number of each of these types of triangles when all
squares in $S$ are dissected this way,
but the triangles of types 1 or 4 each contain two small "below" triangles and
no small "above" triangles, and the only way to make the "above" and "below"
numbers equal is to have an equal number of triangles of types 5 or 8.
Applying similar reasoning to the other four kinds of large triangle, we can conclude that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
n_1 + n_4 &=& n_5 + n_8 \ \mbox{and}\\
n_3 + n_6 &=& n_7 + n_2.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Moreover, each cycle must contain equal numbers of edges going left and right
as well as equal numbers of edges going up and down, so
$$\begin{eqnarray}
n_1 + n_8 &=& n_4 + n_5 \ \mbox{and}\\
n_2 + n_3 &=& n_6 + n_7.
\end{eqnarray}$$

That's eight equations in eight unknowns, but the equations are not all independent.
In fact, by subtracting $n_1 + n_4 = n_5 + n_8$ from $n_1 + n_8 = n_4 + n_5$
we find that  $n_8 - n_4 = n_4 - n_8$ and therefore $n_4 = n_8$.
Similarly, $n_1 = n_5$, $n_2 = n_6$, and $n_3 = n_7$.
The first four equations are therefore just four different restatements
of the equation
$$n_1 + n_2 = n_3 + n_4.$$
The total number of triangles, however, is
$$\begin{eqnarray}
n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 + n_5 + n_6 + n_7 + n_8
&=& 2(n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4) \\
&=& 2(n_1 + n_2 + n_1 + n_2) \\
&=& 4(n_1 + n_2)
\end{eqnarray}$$
which proves that the number of triangles is a multiple of $4$.