# A Finite Square of Unit Squares is chosen. Triangle Proof problem.

Tags: geometry

A finite set S of unit squares is chosen out of a large grid of unit squares. The
squares of S are tiled with isosceles right triangles of hypotenuse 2 so that the triangles do not overlap each other, do not extend past S, and all of S is fully covered by the triangles. Additionally, the hypotenuse of each triangle lies along a grid line, and the vertices of the triangles lie at the corners of the squares. Show that the number of triangles must be a
multiple of 4.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073668/isoceles-triangles-on-a-grid-proof?rq=1 but I see that the deadline for the contest has passed, so presumably it is OK to post answers now.

Comment: @Davidk any thoughts?

Comment: I've posted my own answer to the earlier question. If you want to check the work you've done, however, you need to include that work in your question.